# Azure Key Vault Config Builder in 4.7.1

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

We can't go to .net core yet in my company.  I'm trying to investigate how to best use the azure key vault to store configuration items for our api app services.

I have a simple webapi project with this global.asax file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.WebHost;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault;

namespace kv.api
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

            LoadAzureKeyVaultSettings();
        }


        protected void LoadAzureKeyVaultSettings()
        {
            var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider("RunAs=CurrentUser;");

            var kvClient = new KeyVaultClient((authority, resource, scope) => tokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback(authority, resource, scope));

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddAzureKeyVault("https://mykvurihere.vault.azure.net/", kvClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());

            builder.Build();
        }
    }

}
```

Then i have a simple webapi endpoint here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using kv.api.Models;

namespace kv.api.Controllers
{
    public class SettingsController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Method that returns all the keys out of the Configuration Manager's App Settings.  Can use this endpoint to test KeyVault integrations.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>List of Settings</returns>
        public IEnumerable<Setting> GetAllSettings()
        {
            var settings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys
                .Select(key => new Setting()
                {
                    Key = key,
                    Value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key]
                })
                .ToList();

            return settings;
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles, I get no runtime exception, but this endpoint isn't yielding my configs from the key vault (I do get the appSettings defined in my web.config).  What am I missing here?

--- UPDATE 
It appears that the key vault metrics reported in the azure portal are showing that my app is successfully retrieving the secrets, but they are not being added to the app's AppSettings...

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I did my fair share of figuring this one out so I decided to write a quite lengthy blog post about it which you can find [here](https://blog.bozso.dev/2019/03/18/key-vault-asp-net.html).

In a nutshell, in my opinion the best way to integrate the Key Vault config builder is not through .NET code, but simply by [adding Key Vault as a connected service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service#add-key-vault-support-to-your-project), then set it up in your Web.config, like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
      <add name="AzureKeyVault" vaultName="your vault's name" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
    </builders>
  </configBuilders>
  <appSettings configBuilders="AzureKeyVault">
    <add key="MyValue" value="Value from Web.config" />
  </appSettings>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Then if you set up authentication properly between your Key Vault and your app, add a secret to your Key Vault with the name of "MyValue", it will be replaced at runtime and you will be able to access the secret from Key Vault in your application like this:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyValue"]
```

Comment: Nice article. Is the Environment configuration builder necessary to make it work ? Couln't the vaultname be retreived from appsettings without it ?

Comment: Good point. At the time of writing the article, there was no config builder that could read from the app settings of an Azure Web App, that's why I fell back to the environment one. I checked now, and it seems there's a new config builder now which uses the (currently in preview) Azure App Configuration service: https://github.com/aspnet/MicrosoftConfigurationBuilders#azureappconfigurationbuilder
This might be also an option here.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution but it seems really wonky... Posting it here to get feedback.  What I ended up doing is manually setting key/values in the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings collection like so:

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault;
using ConfigurationBuilder = Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder;

namespace kv.api
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

            LoadAzureKeyVaultSettings();
        }


        protected void LoadAzureKeyVaultSettings()
        {
           var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureServiceTokenProviderConnectionString"]);

           var kvClient =  new KeyVaultClient(
                new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(tokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddAzureKeyVault("https://mykvurihere.vault.azure.net/", kvClient,
                    new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());

           var config = builder.Build();

           foreach (var keyValuePair in config.AsEnumerable())
           {
               ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Set(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
           }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes senses because the `ConfigurationManager` does not know about other settings. The right approach would be to inject an instance of the `IConfiguration` (the `config` object) in the `SettingsController` class.