# Azure Key Vault Connected Service to ASP.NET 4.7.1: CompilationLock exception

Tags: asp.net, azure-keyvault

We're trying to move our application secrets into Azure Key Vault, so I've upgraded our ASP.NET Web app project to 4.7.1 and followed the steps to [add Key Vault as a connected service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service), using my Visual Studio Enterprise subscription to create the Vault.  I'm logged into my account with the subscription in VS, and the "Add Connected Service" functionality was successful, I've added the configuration sections in the web.config, as explained in the linked documentation:

```
  <configSections>
    <section
      name="configBuilders"
      type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
      restartOnExternalChanges="false"
      requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
      <add
        name="AzureKeyVault"
        vaultName="MyVaultName"
        type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"
        vaultUri="https://MyVaultName.vault.azure.net/" />
    </builders>
  </configBuilders>
```

However, the moment I add the `configBuilders="AzureKeyVault"` attribute to the `appSettings` tag and build, I receive a

> The type initializer for 'System.Web.Compilation.CompilationLock' threw an exception.

I'm pretty new (okay, complete noob) with ConfigBuilder functionality, so I presume I'm missing something simple.  I seem to also have replicated the final solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746290/azure-key-vault-config-builder-in-4-7-1), with no joy.

What am I missing?  tia

Answer (score 1):

I follow the tutorial and it works fine in my site.

It may caused by your upgrade of .net framework.

Try to re-install of .NET and clean the project then restart Visual Studio to fix the issue.

Comment: Didn't help.  Neither did an update of VS, although I was already well past minimum version mentioned in the tutorial.

However, I created a new project from scratch, followed the steps in that project, and it worked fine.  I guess I just have to dig into this app and see what might be tripping it up.

Comment: I think when you upgrade .net framework to 4.71, something may have not change. So it causes the error.